# Unusual slow SSD on RAID 0 performance

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd, performance, raid

I'm using a [ThunderBay 4](https://www.owcdigital.com/products/thunderbay-4) external enclosure as my main storage and backup unit. Recently I bought two 1TB Samsung EVO 860 SSD to improve performance of my data drives. I installed them using [NewerTech adaptors](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/NewerTech/ADPTADRV/) and formatted them in RAID 0 using Disk Utility RAID assistant. (I already tried with OWC RAID software with same results)

So I have:

- The two first bays with the SSDs in RAID 0 (for data)
- The following two with 2TB HD in RAID 0 (for backups)

The problem is that I'm getting **write speeds of around 100MB/s** on the data RAID when I should be getting around 800MB/s.

Read speeds are as expected, around 750MB/s.

Without RAID, the same happens, I get around 500MB/s read speed but only 100MB/s write speeds.

Any idea of what could be causing this?

UPDATE:
After trying with all available chunk sizes (from 32k to 256k) for the RAID, still getting the same results.

**Extra inforamtion**

- Using 15" MacBookPro13,3 (2016)
- MacOS Mojave 10.14.1
- Measured with both BlackMagic Disk speed test and iStatus menus.
- Drives firmware revision: RVT01B6Q

Comment: Firstly check the firmware. Also manually run trim on them.

Comment: I updated the post to reflect the firmware version, I doesn't look that there is an update on Samsung website. Now I'm trying to find how to run trim in an external drive

Comment: Actually I only know how to update the firmware using Samsung Magician...

Comment: @PabloLorenzo - Depending on the controller, it might not support TRIM,  have you contacted the manufacturer for assistance?

Comment: I did, still waiting for an answer. I don't think is a trim problem anyway

Comment: Is your BIOS/UEFI set to ACHI? Is write caching enabled? It might also be some incompatibility with the SATA(?) ports. I also note this advertisement found on the ThunderBay 4 site: "I’m getting about 400—500MB/s", so it seems to me that it's doubtful you will get 800MB/s with it.

Comment: Remove the NewerTech adapter to remove a variable from this equation.

Comment: Do both RAID volumes behave the same? I assume without the new SSDs you got the high writing speed? I assume the HDs/SSDs in use are SATA? Can you attach them directly to a e/SATA controller an measure the MB/s (without the raid or any other interface in between)?

Answer (score 1):

After many experimentation I finally tried **removing the adaptors**, attaching the SSDs directly to the SATA interface and creating the RAID again.

**It works fine**, I'm getting the expected ~800MB/s read and writes speeds.